# Es seguro que un servidor confíe en datos que llegan a través de internet

Tags: http, seguridad, https

Estoy haciendo un ecommerce que solicita los datos de los productos a un servicio de cms externo. Ocurre que para la parte del pago: desde el cliente (navegador del comprador) me llega los id de los productos a mi servidor, y ademas desde mi servidor estoy solicitando los datos de los productos a ese servicio cms externo con un get (específicamente estoy consultando el id y el precio) para ya después comparar los ids y hacer las debidas sumas y calcular el total y crear la transacción con el debido monto. Entonces mi duda entra ahí, es seguro que yo este utilizando esos datos que me llegan desde el cms a través de la red para yo calcular los precios?, hay alguna manera de que intervengan esos datos?, y sí existen riesgos que solución me pudieran recomendar.

nota: todas las consultas se hacen sobre https.

Comment: solo quiero saber si es que puedo confiar en los datos que me llegan al hacer un get a través de https, mas que nada quiero una respuesta de si si o no puedo confiar en los datos

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es, si puedo confiar en los datos, ya que al hacer la solicitud a través de https implica que estoy comunicándome y solicitando los datos al servidor correcto. Explicando un poco mejor, con https entra en juego la autoridad de certificados que firma la clave pública del servidor al cual quiero consultar la información de esta manera puedo saber que me comunico con el servidor correcto, y se evita cualquier ataque man in the middle. Además https nos brinda encriptación en los datos que están siendo transmitidos, esto quiere decir que los datos solo podrán ser descifrados o leídos por los dos servidores o cliente y servidor en cuestión.

[Video sobre certificado de autoridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ItJ-VqYo_s)

Comment: Aun asi, existen varios vectores de ataque y tambien hay varios trucos que se pueden usar para quitar el https de la pagina, asimismo se puede realizar la inyección de scripts al navegador del usuario, claro esto son ataques dirigidos a usuarios que realmente se obtengan beneficios. como se dijo, es un tema amplio y el cifrado por https debe ser una de muchas capas de seguridad integrada al sistema.